# Ruby garbage collection on anonymous classes using define_method

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection

I'm trying to track down a memory leak in the [state_machine gem](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) that I began to notice when I started dynamically generating state machines using anonymous classes [per the README example](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine#static--dynamic-definitions). [This gist](https://gist.github.com/jhuckabee/5978668) demonstrates how I uncovered the issue originally.

I've been able to narrow down the problem to the way helper methods get defined in the state machine gem which I've summarized [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/jhuckabee/5981406).

My question is, what is the `define_method` block doing that causes the anonymous class not to get garbage collected? Commenting those 3 lines (18-20) seems to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

**Update:** I'm using Ruby 2.0.0p195

Comment: Would be good to know which Ruby implementation you're using.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm using 2.0.0p195. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2013/03/03/dynamic_method_definitions.html) explains the problem.

> The main down side is that define_method creates a closure. The closure could hold references to large objects, and those large objects will never be garbage collected.